# Can CSS or JS effect the submission of a form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a large form spread over 3 tabs. The tabs are controlled by JS which simply changes the css property display: block to display:none depending what tab you click on.

This form also submits data to 3 different tables via php. When i submit my form at the end of the the 3rd tab some of my data is missing in a table that accepts multiple rows (the other two tables only accept a single row) In this section of the form I let the user add as many "Rooms" as they need. The rooms are just a few selection boxes, and the extra selection boxes are also added with JS. When i submit my form only the first "room" is added to the table.

I am positive every thing is working as if I remove the tabs it works perfectly or even if i add all three sections of the form to one tab it works. Below is the PHP that inputs the rooms and loops depending how many there are. Sorry this is a very large form so i dont want to just stick it all in, but it is all very simple and all working. Please let me know if I should add any other part of my code if that helps.

```
$level = $_POST['level'];
$room_type = $_POST['room_type'];
$width = $_POST['width'];
$length = $_POST['length'];

$num_rooms = count($level);             

for($x=0;$x<$num_rooms;$x++)   
{

    $room_insert = mysqli_query($dbcon, "INSERT INTO listing_rooms (Listing_ID, Level, Type, Length, Width) VALUES ('$listing_id', '$level[$x]', '$room_type[$x]', '$length[$x]', '$width[$x]')") or die(mysql_error());

 }
```

To trigger this I have an if(isset()) just above this. Thanks for any help.

This is the JS that shows and hides the tabs...

```
function showHideTab(tab_id) {

    if (tab_id == 'details_tab'){

        document.getElementById('listing_details').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('listing_info').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('photo_upload').style.display='none';

    }else if (tab_id == 'info_tab') {

        document.getElementById('listing_info').style.display='block'; 
        document.getElementById('listing_details').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('photo_upload').style.display='none'; 

    }
    else if (tab_id == 'upload_tab') {
        document.getElementById('photo_upload').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('listing_info').style.display='none'; 
        document.getElementById('listing_details').style.display='none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Firebug or Developer Tools or similar tool and see in Network tab what is actually sent over network when form is submitted.

Comment: That would be a wild guess without seeing the generated HTML and the Javascript that generated it.

Comment: As i said its all very simple and all works on its own. What would be the best to post here... the JS?? the HTML is just input text, selection and check-boxes.

Comment: To answer the title question: no, CSS won't affect the form submit, only the HTML will.

Comment: count() — Count all elements in an array, or something in an object, your not passing an array or object to the function, so its just going to return 1, hence the single row insert... **also why are you not using parametrised query's**

Comment: The array is multiple selections boxes all the same name="level[]" if i have all sections on the same tab count works fine otherwise count returns 1 and it only holds the very first value instead of all the values entered.

Comment: @GifCo its possible then that `$_POST['level']` is not being set, due to something also you should check **every** input that its set, check the error log and enable error reporting...

Comment: @Loz Cherone - thats the weird thing it is being set because it does store the first value i enter into my table. And if i put the entire form in one big <div> i get as many values as I enter. Im also not getting any errors. Is it possible that having a starting form tab with so many div's in between the end form tag and also having JS show and hide those divs could cause an issue?

Answer (score 0):

As I thought this was a very simple error. As i said I have 3 divs being shown or hidden by JS. My issue was I had my opening FORM tag inside my first div!

I still dont know why everything other then the array of "rooms" worked fine regardless of where the opening form tag was, and even the array held the first value?